# How to place elements proportionally in the HBox/VBox using javafx/fxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I try to place buttons and text evenly in the window. I use FXML for javafx project:

```xml
<VBox>
  <HBox>
        <TextField promptText="Text1" prefWidth="60" alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
            <padding>
                <Insets left="10" right="30"/>
            </padding>
        </TextField>
        <Label text="Some text"/>
        <TextField promptText="Text2" prefWidth="60" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT">
            <padding>
                <Insets left="30" right="10"/>
            </padding>
        </TextField>
    </HBox>
</VBox>
```

I use `padding`, 'alignment' properties but nothing help, elements are offset:

[image]

How to correctly to place elements in window?

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Make sure the `VBox` is filling the width of the window

   - (your code snippet doesn’t indicate if it is in another container).
2. Make sure the `HBox` fills the width of the `VBox`

   - add `fillWidth=“true”` to the `VBox` element.
3. Let each component grow in the `HBox`

   - add `HBox.hgrow = “ALWAYS”` and `maxWidth = “Infinity”` to the text fields and label.
   - remove the padding and
     insets, and existing preferred widths.

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<VBox fillWidth="true" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <HBox>
        <TextField promptText="Text1" maxWidth="Infinity" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" text="Some text" maxWidth="Infinity" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
        <TextField promptText="Text2" maxWidth="Infinity" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
    </HBox>
</VBox>
```

and the application file:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 600, 400);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```